# Azure HDInsight Jupyter notebook not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I have deployed a HDInsight 3.6 Spark (2.3) cluster on Microsoft Azure with the standard configurations (Location = Central US, Head Nodes = D12 v2 (x2) - 8 cores, Worker Nodes = D13 v2 (x4)) - 32 cores).

Launch Jupyter notebook and when selecting spark notebook gives a weird error which i am not able to figure out .

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please copy-paste the text of the error and/or provide a sample code. Indeed, the image is not easy to read and text instead of image could improve the visibilty of your question, thus helping other user facing the same issue.

Comment: Used inline image

Comment: Facing the same issue myself. What does azure test ! A jupyter notebook which is the starting point itself is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue with 2 steps:

1. Connect to headnode via ssh and change content of file - /usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbformat/_version.py. replace 5 to 4(by sudo vim..)

[image]

2. Restart Jupyter service via Ambari

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am on the same boat as you and it was frustrating. I couldn't make the jupyter notebook work on azure . But I was able to run spark commands through pyspark shell. My experience in this blog

https://krishansubudhi.github.io/datascience/2020/01/12/hdinsight.html

However, I was able to open jupyter notebook using AWS. There is a section on this in the end of the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

The HDInsight team is in the process of rolling out a self-healing action for this issue. Once the self-healing action has been deployed, the Jupyter service on the affected clusters will have to be started again for the changes to take effect. I will update this thread as the fix is deployed.

Comment: This issue has now been fixed in the Azure HDInsight service. You should no longer see this error.

Answer (score -1):

The code is **converting jupyter notebook to v5 format** which is supported only in [Python 3](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id1).

You need to **use python 3.5+** built-in anaconda environment or [setup virtual python 3 environmet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation)